# Html dialog element make it focusable when open

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog

I have a dialog that contains a button and when I open my dialog element I want the dialog to be focused is that event available with a native dialog element?
I would not like to use a focus trap, is this possible with a native dialog element?

here is my example code:

```css
html {
  block-size: 100%;
  color-scheme: dark light;
}

body {
  min-block-size: 100%;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <p>Hi, I'm a dialog.</p>
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button onclick="dialog.showModal()">Open Dialog</button>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/web-dot-dev/pen/popLbZB

Answer (score 1):

this?

```js
dialog.showModal();  // show modal dialog on init page load...

document.querySelector('#bt-open-Dialog')
  .addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
    dialog.showModal();
    });
```

```css
html {
  block-size: 100%;
  color-scheme: dark light;
  }
body  {
  min-block-size : 100%;
  font-family    : system-ui, sans-serif;
  display        : grid;
  place-content  : center;
  margin         : 0;
  }
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <p>Hi, I'm a MODAL dialog.</p>
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button id="bt-open-Dialog">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: Its working when modal is initialy opened, but when I close it and try to open it again the button is not focues on tab key ?